# php 2 foreachloops

Tags: php, foreach

I want to output the key of the associative array, if the preg_match function returns true.

But somehow the second foreach loop returns just one key.

Why is this so?

This is my php code:

```
<?php

     $log = file('ab.boerse.de.access.log.2');

     foreach ($log as $key => $value)
     {
         $result = explode(" ", $value);

         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($result);
         echo "</pre>";

         foreach ($result as $key2 => $value2)
         {
             echo "<pre>";
             print_r($key2);
             echo "</pre>";

             if (preg_match("/somedata/", $value2))
             {
                 print_r($key2);
             }
             else
             {
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
            
 ?>
```

And this is the outputed array with the key "0" below it:

```
Array (
    [0] => localhost
    [1] => somedata
    [2] => somedata
    [3] => somedata
    [4] => somedata
    [5] => somedata
    [6] => somedata
    [7] => somedata
    [8] => somedata
    [9] => somedata
    [10] => somedata
    [11] => somedata
    
) 0
```

Comment: Can you provide a **very brief** example of your input data? Also, because you are outputting HTML, you need to show us that, and not the rendered HTML. In the sample above, you aren't showing us the pre tags, although they are implied.

Comment: what do you mean with input data, the data from the file?

Comment: and arent the pre tags there, around the print_r´s? :)

Comment: Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @ChrisHaas you have the input for the 2nd foreach. The input file is not important.

Comment: @ChrisHaas The `<pre>` tags wont come with the `print_r()` output as there is no second parameter in the `print_r()` to stop its output going straight to the browser  `print_r($key2,1);` would fix that

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, I completely misunderstood what the OP's problem was, I thought they were trying to determine where their stray trailing `0` was coming in, and since they were manually echoing the `<pre>` tags, I wanted to see those in relation to the other parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First items value is `localhost` and not `somedata`, so the regex does not match anything and it executes the break ending the 2nd foreach. Try using `continue` instead of `break` if you want to skip unwanted items. `continue` terminates just the current iteration of the cycle and continues with next item.

Comment: I mean, it's the last instruction in the loop, so it should just be removed altogether.